# How to perform the data sampling in Flink streaming

Tags: flink-streaming

Flink appears to have the data samplers but i do not see any examples of how to apply the data samplers in Flink streaming application.

Is it possible to apply data samplers in Flink streaming application? I am interested in using `ReservoirSamplerWithoutReplacement` in my application, any hints would be helpful.

Comment: I use windowing, the only way to apply is to implement ProcessWindowFunction and collect all the elements into arraylist and apply the random sampler?

Answer (score 0):

Use windowing with an [AggregateFunction](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/api/common/functions/AggregateFunction.html). The accumulator you create for this would be something that maintains the data needed for the `ReservoirSamplerWithoutReplacement` algorithm.